# How to get WHERE come after group by in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working with a dataset, I used GROUP BY to get the count of one of the columns. Then, I want to filter the columns with count > 2, I find that WHERE does not work after GROUP BY, may I ask what should I do?

For example, for the id_table with only one column id with the numbers [2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2], I want to count each and find which id appears more than two times, in this case, the output should be 2 since it appeared 3 times. My code is like below:

```
SELECT id
FROM id_table                       
GROUP BY id
WHERE count(id) > 2;
```

The error code is: near "WHERE": syntax error

Comment: Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`

Answer (score 2):

Try this (`HAVING` instead of `WHERE`):

```
SELECT id
  FROM id_table                       
 GROUP BY id
HAVING count(id) > 2
;
```